# Windows Batch for-loop. Problems with doublequotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, wildcard, quotes

Lets say i want to copy a file from one location to another with this code:

```
@set FILE=%1
@set SCRDIR=C:\test dir
@set DSTDIR=%SCRDIR%\temp

for %%f in ("%SCRDIR%\%FILE%") do @(
    echo Copying "%%f" to "%DSTDIR%"
    copy "%%f" "%DSTDIR%"
)
```

The file exists:

```
 C:\test dir>dir /b copyme.txt
copyme.txt
```

First i call the script with the name of the file as argument i want to copy:

```
C:\test dir>test.bat rename.txt

C:\test dir>for %f in ("C:\test dir\rename.txt") do @(
echo Copying "%f" to "C:\test dir\temp"
 copy "%f" "C:\test dir\temp"
)
Copying ""C:\test dir\rename.txt"" to "C:\test dir\temp"
The system cannot find the file specified..
```

The above copy command fails, because of the extra quotes...

Now i call the script with the file name containing a wildcard `*` :

```
C:\test dir>test.bat copyme.*

C:\test dir>for %f in ("C:\test dir\copyme.*") do (
echo Copying "%f" to "C:\test dir\temp"
 copy "%f" "C:\test dir\temp"
)

C:\test dir>(
echo Copying "C:\test dir\copyme.txt" to "C:\test dir\temp"
 copy "C:\test dir\copyme.txt" "C:\test dir\temp"
)
Copying "C:\test dir\copyme.txt" to "C:\test dir\temp"
        1 file(s) copied.
```

In the above example, where im using a wildcard, it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Why does windows add extra quotes when im not using wildcards? Or is it omitting the extra quotes, because im using wildcards?
I have to quote the path\filename for the `FOR` loop in order to handle paths, which contain blanks, so omitting those is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when there are no wildcards, `for` command doesn't check if the file exists, so effectively treats its name as a string literal, quotes included.
Just use `"%%~f"` instead of `"%%f"`